# What is this type of hook bolt called?

Tags: fixtures

This fixture is attaching fibre cement panels to 30 mm steel angle purlins.

I need some new ones or equivalent fixtures, but terms like "square hook bolt" are not returning anything useful.

[image]

What is the name for this fixture?

(If you look closely, the steel has been mounted the 'wrong' way up, so the edge is towards the roof, and roofing hook bolts won't work.)

Comment: Think it is a piece of bent steel with a threaded hole.  Maybe home made.

Comment: **Beam clamp** might get you adequately similar things. Picture leaves some details unclear.